# Extjs adding checkbox to container.viewport

Tags: extjs, checkbox

i am new to extjs and i am trying to add a checkbox to my container.viewport gridpanel.

This is my code:

```
                                        xtype: 'gridpanel',
                                        flex: 2,
                                        autoScroll: true,
                                        title: 'title',
                                        store: 'OutgoingDataStore',

                                        columns: [
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                                align: 'right',
                                                dataIndex: 'calls_m',
                                                text: 'Calls Monthly'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                                                align: 'right',
                                                dataIndex: 'check',
                                                text: 'check',

                                            }..
```

without the checkcolumnit works fine, but when i add it the app shows empty page and on the console i see :'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined '

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version you're using. In 4.2.0, the CheckColumn was moved into the core library. If you're using an earlier version (which it seems like you are), then the CheckColumn is just an extension, so you'd need to include it from the examples/ux folder.

Answer (score 0):

In 4.2.0 you would do it like this.

```
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    flex: 2,
    autoScroll: true,
    title: 'title',
    store: 'OutgoingDataStore',
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'), // This will add check column
    columns: [
       {
           xtype: 'gridcolumn',
           align: 'right',
           dataIndex: 'calls_m',
           text: 'Calls Monthly'
       }
     ...
```